# How do I set the value of a color static resource in XAML from another color static resource in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin.Forms, I am trying to create a theme file with some base colors and derived colors defined in a resource dictionary. How exactly do I make one color resource derive its value from another color resource? I am trying to achieve something like the below code:

`<Color x:Key="NeutralColor0">#000000</Color>
<Color x:Key="BorderColorDark" Value={StaticResource NeutralColor0}></Color>`

Also is it possible to achieve something like the following code?

`<Color x:Key="BorderColorDark" Value={StaticResource NeutralColor0} Converter="{local:MyMagicColorConverter param1=10, param2=20}"></Color>`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your purpose? I don't think you can do it. If you want pass arguments to the color ,you can implement it in a specific page or element .

Comment: Like I said in the question, I am trying to create a theme file. Its something similar to how you make a template for a website. You define base variables such as primary colors, neutral colors, fonts etc in LESS/SASS. And then create more complex styles over them.

Comment: You can create a subclass of content page or DataTemplate .And set the value of these property .